# JavaScript Standard Style does not recognize Mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have a [Mocha](http://mochajs.org/) test file that looks like this:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect
var muting = require('../muting')

describe('muting', function () {
  describe('init()', function () {
    it('should inject an object into twitter', function () {
      var twitter = 'twitter'
      muting.init(twitter)
      expect(muting.twitter).to.equal(twitter)
    })
  })
})
```

When I run `mocha` from the CLI, it runs the test successfully.

When I run `standard` (the executable for [JavaScript Standard Style](https://github.com/feross/standard)) I get errors on Mocha's framework functions like so:

```
standard: Use JavaScript Standard Style (https://github.com/feross/standard)   
c:\..\test\index.js:5:0: 'describe' is not defined.  
c:\..\test\index.js:6:2: 'describe' is not defined.  
c:\..\test\index.js:7:4: 'it' is not defined.
```

What's the cleanest way to make Standard not complain about these functions?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to list every single global variable in your package.json

You can specify environments instead like this:

```
"standard": {
  "env": [ "mocha" ]
}
```

Source: [Official ESLint configuration docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments).

Comment: Good solution. Doesn't that mean I can call `it` in regular non-test code and it will pass linting? In other words. Can it be restricted only to test classes?

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem... `package.json` settings are 'global' for linter. You can bypass it by providing different CLI arguments for different files: something like `standard --env mocha test/**/js` for lint-tests (not tested), but IRL i never had a need to tweak settings like this.

Comment: If using jest, you also can: "standard": { "env": [ "jest" ]}

Comment: To add to the comment by @palafox_e you can find out which values are available by navigating to: 

https://github.com/sindresorhus/globals/blob/master/globals.json

Comment: I'm using `jest` but I don't know why only works for mocha and not jest!

Answer (score 217):

I prefer to edit my `.eslintrc` and add mocha to env section:

```
...
"env": {
  "commonjs": true,
  "node": true,
  "mocha": true
},
...
```

this way my `package.json` file is kept clean, also vscode plugin for eslint understands it better

Comment: Yes, this should be the approved answer.

Comment: I also second the fact that this should be the approved answer.

Comment: Does `standard` track `.eslintrc`?

Comment: This answer does not appear to be about the `JavaScript Standard Style` package as asked by the OP.

Answer (score 66):

while eslint's comment configuration works great for a single file, I prefer to use standard's [`package.json`](https://github.com/feross/standard#i-use-a-library-that-pollutes-the-global-namespace-how-do-i-prevent-variable-is-not-defined-errors) `globals` configuration to do this for my projects. E.g.

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "standard": {
    "globals": [
      "describe",
      "context",
      "before",
      "beforeEach",
      "after",
      "afterEach",
      "it",
      "expect"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 59):

for eslint use this line on the beginning of **test_file.js**

```
/* eslint-env mocha */
```

Comment: I prefer this solution!

Comment: That's not a solution if you have to add it for every test file

Comment: @Peadar Creating multiple `.eslintrc.json` is also not really beautiful, just because you do not want to add one line to the test. On the other hand creating another `.eslintrc.json` makes sense if you need more than that config for mocha, for example an extra plugin or so.

Comment: This work for me! A simple solution.

Answer (score 41):

You can use the same solution as for [web workers](https://github.com/feross/standard#what-about-web-workers)

```
/* global describe it */
var expect = require('chai').expect
var muting = require('../muting')

describe('muting', function () {
  describe('init()', function () {
    it('should inject an object into twitter', function () {
     var twitter = 'twitter'
     muting.init(twitter)
     expect(muting.twitter).to.equal(twitter)
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by [Nick Tomlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048479/nick-tomlin) you just need to declare globals.

I use to put it in the command line, since I have different globals for tests as for sources or different parts of the project.

For tests we should use

```
standard --global describe --global it test/
```

elsewhere in my project I want to lint code that uses jQuery so I use

```
standard --global $ src/client/
```

### Bonus tip

If you are using vim with Syntastic you maybe want to add to your *.vimrc*

```
let b:syntastic_checkers = ['standard']
let g:syntastic_javascript_standard_args = "--global $ --global it --global describe"
```