# How to let visual studio code recognize `before`, and `after` keyword in mocha?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, mocha.js

I'm using visual studio code v1.19.1 to write unit test with mocha.

I found that when I hover the mouse over the `after` keyword, vs code says `[standard] 'after' is not defined. (no-undef)`. This means that it doesn't recognize `after` keyword.

It seems that this problem has something to do with [JavaScript Standard Style](https://standardjs.com/) plugin.

I've read this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018271/javascript-standard-style-does-not-recognize-mocha). But adding

```
"standard": {
  "env": [ "mocha" ]
}
```

or

```
 "standard": {
    "globals": [
      "describe",
      "context",
      "before",
      "beforeEach",
      "after",
      "afterEach",
      "it",
      "expect"
    ]
  }
```

to `package.json` doesn't work in my case.

What might be wrong with my visual studio code or javascript standard style plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that this error happens because my `package.json` file is not located in the root folder of visual studio code.

After moving it to the root folder of visual studio code, vscode recognizes `before`, `after` keywords in mocha.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem, but unfortunately could not move `package.json` out of its current directory as I am working within a monorepo. The workaround that worked for me was to directly import the `mocha` library inside my test files by defining its path as follows:

`const mocha = require('../../../node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js');`

and then use declare its keywords as follows:

`mocha.before(() => {})`